# R - infinite loop if for dropping columns

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I am trying to remove useless column from a data frame. I used a while loop with an if statement, and it seems that it never leaves the if statement :

```
it = 1
while (it < ncol(testing))
{
  if ("drop" %in% CategOfData[it,])
   {testing[,it]<-NULL}
  else it = it + 1
}
```

the if loop works as long as it's not nested in a while loop.

testing is my data frame containing 400 rows and 12 columns,

CategOfData is a data frame of 12 rows and 2 columns, CategOfData contains the header of my df "testing" and the categories of it, 3 rows contain the word "drop"

I tested this code by replacing {testing[,it]<-NULL} with {jkl = jkl + 0.5},
And again the code ran long, I cut it short, asked the console what the value of jkl was, and it returned a number well over 800 000, while it should have returned 2.5 (1 + 3*0.5)

I don't understand why it nevers enters the else part of the code. which makes the while loop infinite since "it" never incrementes

I would use a for loop, but R doesn't agree since I'm dropping columns as I go.

the type of CategOfData :

```
   > CategOfData [1,]
              header              x 
         "PIERRE.MARIE"         "drop"
```

and "testing"

```
 > head(testing[,1])
 [1] PIERRE-MARIE PIERRE-MARIE PIERRE-MARIE PIERRE-MARIE PIERRE-MARIE  PIERRE-MARIE
       Levels: LAURENNE PIERRE-MARIE
```

Can you help me pinpoint where the problem lies please?

I tried this instead

```
    it = 1
    rem = ncol(testing)
    while (it < rem)
    {
      if ("drop" %in% CategOfData2[it,])
       {testing[,it]<-NULL
        CategOfData2 = CategOfData2[-it,]
        rem = rem - 1
     }
     it = it + 1
  }
```

It works ~Ok, but doesn't remove the last column which is a drop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be solved with two lines of R code:

```
drop <- apply(CategOfData, 1, function(x) { "drop" %in% x })
testing <- testing[, !drop]
```

And this is a good example of the kind of power which R has, when you use it correctly.

Comment: I tried that, it returns an error : 

"Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , drop, value = NULL) : 
  le tableau de remplacement a 0 éléments, et il en faut 1476"



Saying the dataframe of replacement has 0 elements, and needs 1476

Comment: Can you execute `drop <- apply(CategOfData, 1, function(x) { "drop" %in% x })` by itself?  If so, then what does `drop` contain in your console?

Comment: Yes I can,
it returns a string of logical values : "[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE"

Comment: Updated my answer.  You don't need to use `NULL` to remove columns, you can simply subset the `testing` data frame.  This should work for you now.

Comment: It works a little bit too well, it removes all the columns I want to keep ^^

But, testing <- testing[, -drop] doesn't work either,

I am trying the subset function, I am not sure from which package, but it keeps sending errors.

Did I mention I was fairly new to programming in R?

Comment: Updated again.  I negated the `drop` vector.